# SVN Repo Access Control Issue

Tags: svn, authorization

What I am trying to do with svn only allow a specific group to have access to specific **files**. Those files are in random directories with other files on the same directory level.

Example:

```
/branches/libraries/all_access_file.php
/branches/libraries/some_access_file.php
/branches/codebase/lots_of_private_files.php
/branches/codebase/one_file_that_someone_can_see.php
```

When I set a specific file permission such as

```
[repo:/branches/librares/some_access_file.php]
@admin = rw
@devs = rw
@some_guy = rw
```

My expected result is to see on svn co that anyone in "some_guy" group only gets that one file. But they get a forbidden error because they are implicitly denied by another rule:

```
[repo:/branches]
@admin = rw
@devs = rw
```

What is the proper way to essentially deny access to an entire repository except for one file (whose directory structure is completely random and irrevelant)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have the @rw in your file? If so, I don't think that is valid and may be messing up your authorization.

I have also always seen/done this from parent to child... it may be that svn parses the authentication in order, but I doubt it. So, your file might look like:

```
[repo:/branches]
@admin = rw
@devs  = rw

[repo:/branches/librares/some_access_file.php]
@some_guy = rw
```

Also, do you allow anonymous access? If you add

@some_guy = r to the /branches does this allow the users of your group to acess/write the file in question?

Finally you may want to, as a test, add a specific user name with rw access to the file..

thatguy = rw

and see if that works. It may be the users you testing isn't actually in the some_guy group?

Keep in mind that a user can't checkout (svn co) and individual file even if they have access to it. They could probably export the individual file if that is all they have access to.

To solve this problem if possible reorganize your project so files you want to control access to are all in a certain folder. This will allow the user to check out that single folder.

If you are just trying to control access to certain files that people won't be editing svn is not the tool you are looking for. Run some type of script with a cron job that updates shared folders which have the correct permissions based on the file system.

Comment: There is no @ in the file. That was a typo.

I have the file just like you put there, where branches is above some_access_file.php

There is no anonymous access allowed.

If I add @some_guy read access to /branches, then when I check out the repo, it allows me to pull all the files instead of just the one I want to give **read** access to. I do not want that group to even be able to read any files but specific ones that I allow. 

The person is absolutely in the group. Whether it's a person or group, the problem is the same.

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do? If the user has access to only that single file I think you have a problem, as you can only check out a folder, you can't check out a single file. The user is going to need read access to the containing folder in order to checkout the file.

Comment: My hope was to check out the project and be able to allow only certain files to be visible, even if they're on the same directory level as other files that should not be able to be seen.

Comment: Yep, that won't work. They could probably export the individual file if that is all they have access to. You cant do "svn co" of a file even if you have access to it.